# How to pass a url to a proxy using xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, proxy, xmlhttprequest

I am using javascript to build an application.  I am trying to access the url through a squid proxy. And the proxy has authentication.

```
 proxy ip : 192.169.0.1:8080
 url i wanna visit is : http://google.com
```

i am currently using (whole code is not posted) =>

```
    xhr.open('GET' 192.169.0.1:8080/ http://www.google.com , true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Proxy-Authorization', 'Basic:' + encodeBase64(proxy.username + ":" + proxy.password));
    xhr.send();
```

why this code doesn't work ?.. What header i need to set to pass the url to the proxy and the authentication parameters if i am using xmlhttprequest ?

Comment: Did you get to work this out?